# AngularJs and or "hbs" (npm)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, npm

Can angularJS replace the use of a "view engine" in nodeJS. I need information like: which one method is a better practice. (MEAN Stack devs use view engine?? or res.sendFile and something like ui-router/angularjs. res.sendFile or res.render. pros cons and stuff like that)

Comment: Generally you would create an angular application, you'd serve that using express's static file serving, then in your express application you'd have your applications API which your angular client side application would make HTTP requests to. You would not use Angular as a templating engine for Express at all, all templating is done on the frontend via angular.

Comment: There was a small hack in Express. If you do `app.get('/*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('yourangularjsindex.html');});` All routes with be replaced to this index file and AngularJS can catch these.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on  you  tasks. But in most cases you don't  need to use res.sendFile and hbs. You can just serve static files as well.